# Difference between -n and -np when running MPI script?

Tags: python, mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi, slurm

I'm learning how to use MPI, and am confused on the difference between -n and -np when calling a script. For reference, I am trying to run the script on a Slurm cluster with OpenMPI 3.

For instance, I can run my script like this:

```
mpirun -n 4 --oversubscribe python par_PyScript2.py
```

or like this:

```
mpirun -np 4 --oversubscribe python par_PyScript2.py
```

Can someone describe what these options actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.0/man1/mpirun.1.php) says that `-n` and `-np` are synonyms. And so are `-c` and `--n`. They instruct `mpirun` to

> Run this many copies of the program on the given nodes.

So it basically is the number of MPI ranks you want. Note that in a Slurm context, you should not specify it explicitly; the information is passed from Slurm to OpenMPI.

Answer (score 2):

Use the manual

```
man mpirun
```

Search for that by typing `/-n` and to go to next match, press `n`.

From the online manual, I see no option `-n`. Though, it is possible that `-n` is just an alias for `-np`